# Fit subview according to screen and disable scroll in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a view controller in which i have added a scroll view under the scroll view there is another subview with name content view. In the content view there is another subview with name fullView, the fullView display on tapgesture, when it shows the fullView it also get scroll according to scrollview height, but i want that the fullView just show according to iphone screen size it does not scroll, 
I had tried this code but it isn't working,

```
CGFloat width = _fullView.frame.size.width;
                   CGFloat height = _fullView.frame.size.height;
```

Comment: you dont want the full view to scroll?...you are not clear ...can you post some more code??.....

Comment: Bro i want that when my fullView opens it should fit on screen and do not scroll. @PulkitKumarSingh

Answer (score 0):

Set scrollview frame to scrollview contentsize

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.width,scrollview.frame.size.height);
```

no matter what frame does the fullview has , scrollview will not scroll.

Please read the documentation of ScrollView.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Comment: bro it will adjust the content size of fullView? @Pulkit Kumar Singh

Comment: No....scrollview scrolls when its contentsize is greater than its frame....so on tap you display fullview ....and set contentsize of scrollview  as i have mentioned in my  answer so that contentsize==frame ...hence scrollview will not scroll @Raheel